# Deconstructing Props from React Component with Typescript and Union Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-props

I've got my Props Interface divided into a base interface and two Union types:

```
interface BaseProps {
  ...
}

interface ControlledInput extends BaseProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: ...;
}

interface UncontrolledInput extends BaseProps {
  defaultValue: string;
  ref: string;
}

export const TextInput:
  React.SFC<ControlledInput | UncontrolledInput> = ({
  type,
  label,
  value,
  ...rest
}) => {
```

However, deconstructing **value** gives me an array, since it doesn't exist on the UncontrolledInputProps.

I reckon I would need a typeguard, something like:

```
if (typeof rest.value === 'string') {
```

I can't really wrap my head around it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer on the official docs:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

So the typeguard to write looks as follows:

```
export function isControlled(input: ITextInputControlledProps | 
ITextInputUncontrolledProps):
  input is ITextInputControlledProps {
    return (input as ITextInputControlledProps).value !== undefined;
}
```

Then in my component i can go:

```
if (isControlled(rest)) {
  const { value, onChange } = rest;
  valueProps = { value, onChange };
} else {
  const { defaultValue, ref } = rest as ITextInputUncontrolledProps;
  valueProps = { defaultValue, ref };
}
```